# What is the spark command to find the operations applied on a specific RDD

Tags: apache-spark

If my RDD value is:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
```

and after some code, if I forgot what operations were applied to `a`, what is the command to find those operations?

Answer (score 0):

[RDD.toDebugString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@toDebugString:String) will give you the required information:

```scala
val a = sc.parallelize(1 to 5)
println(a.toDebugString)
```

prints

```
(4) ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at Test.scala:31 []
```

You can find some more information on how to interpret the debug string [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-lineage.html).

The debug string contains the DAG without data. There is no Spark feature that will "record" all operations including the data. If it is necessary to keep the data, one might try to intercept the Spark API with [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), but this will require a considerable amount of work.

Comment: Thanks Werner for the answer.By using RDD.toDebugString we get the function we have used but is there any way that i can know what are the values used inside the functions i.e. i have to get the 1 to 5 as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I doubt that I have an easy solution for you

Comment: Got it thanks.Is it same for dataframe or is there any change in the command for dataframe.

Comment: you can use [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@explain(extended:Boolean):Unit) for a dataframe